# Duplicate Symbol Error in Binding

Tags: ios, xamarin, afnetworking

I am having this error in my iOS binding project:

`Error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFJSONParser'. (MT5212) 
(AerisMap) Error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: 
/Users/danielknoodle/Documents/AerisMap/AerisMapTest/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/Aeris.a(AFJSONParser+JSONKit.o) (Location related to previous error) (MT5213)
(AerisMap)Error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/danielknoodle/Documents/AerisMap/AerisMapTest/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/Aeris.a(AFJSONParser+SBJSON.o) (Location related to previous error) (MT5213) (AerisMap)`

As we know, an obj.c file that has + sign works similar to a partial class in c#. (please correct me if i am wrong).
i wonder why AFJSONParser+JSONKit.o and AFJSONParser+SBJSON.o are treated as different classes.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".